# Detecting memory leak with libc_malloc_debug_leak.so for specific processes

Tags: debugging, memory, memory-leaks

In Android, for detecting memory leak I am using `libc_malloc_debug_leak.so`. But as soon as I do that it starts tracking memory operation details for all processes which makes the device very slow.

Is there any way I can use this only for my app / process as I am mainly interested in tracking memory operations details only for my app?